# How to open launch.json and scroll to specific configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building an extension. When a user clicks a button, I want to open launch.json (Debug configuration) file and scroll to a specific configuration.

I can use `vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.debug.configure")` to open launch.json file. However I need to scroll to specific configuration.

I want it to work the way VS Code "Open launch.json" button works. [image]